# Row consolidating in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, expression, ssrs-2008-r2

I am running SSRS in Visual Studio 2013 community edition.

My report is showing rent for the "current period" and then has an outside group that shows the "future rent" and $ amount on the right.
Under the first row, I have placed an expression that shows me the $ per SqFt. My question is, how can I have this row that shows in White, appear in the same row as the first "future rent date"? I think I need to fudge with RowNumber! but I am not sure how to tackle this.

Thanks for your input,

Current report
[image: My Report]
Desired outcome below

[image: Desired Outcome]

Dataset below
[image: My Dataset]

Comment: In your current report what differentiates the first 7 columns from the next 3? In your template it looks like they're all on the same line/group. Also, it would be helpful to add a column with the row number so you can see it before trying to write an expression.

Comment: The first 7 are row fields in my Dataset, per the query. They show Each property broken down by their rent, etc. The right 3  then are grouped outside so they can display the Future information by the unit. As I mentioned, the first left row will show the current rent info and the right will show the future under it. I would like to show the PerSqFt values on the same line as the first "Future Date" line.

Comment: Have you already tried setting the visibility of the cell to `=IIF(RowNumber("GroupbyCategory") = 1, False, True)`?

Comment: I have this working on the right side for the future values, as :

`=IIF(Rownumber("UnitNumber1")>1,Fields!OccurredDate.Value,Nothing)`

However, on the left, I am not sure how to nest this correctly into this expression for the first cell in white: `=
IIF(Fields!SqFt.Value = 0, 0, 
(IIF(Fields!ChargeDesc.Value Like "*Base*", CDEC(Fields!Amount.Value), 0) * 
(12 / Fields!SqFt.Value)))`

Thanks for your replies, @StevenWhite

Answer (score 1):

To follow the example you're using on the right and simply nest the functions, it would look like this:

```
=IIF(Rownumber("UnitNumber1") = 2,IIF(Fields!SqFt.Value = 0, 0, (IIF(Fields!ChargeDesc.Value Like "*Base*", CDEC(Fields!Amount.Value), 0) * (12 / Fields!SqFt.Value))),Nothing)
```

This may generate a divide by zero error. See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471817/ssrs-2008-dealing-with-division-by-zero-scenarios) for a solution to that if needed.

Comment: This only hid the values that are displayed in my first figure, in white. Unfortunately, it did not nest them as desired. I appreciate the help, I am still trying to work with the RowNumber! here.