# Avoid divide by zero in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I am working on a report that is attempting to find a percentage. Initially my code would look like:

```
= (Fields!Margin.Value) / (Fields!TotalSales.Value) * 100
```

However the problem is that in some scenarios TotalSales = 0.00 so this is giving me the error. I am not proficient in VBS. How do I do a NULLIF type function to avoid this?

Comment: Check out this post -
 http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Report+Development/121619/

Comment: Thank for the article. Although I don't think this works because instead of simply changing the value in the text field, I need to make sure that the formula used doesn't encounter zero. This just changes the output and doesn't change the value prior to calculation, if I'm understanding the writeup correctly

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times. My favorite solution is to use `If` instead of `IIf`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5471817/2033717 http://stackoverflow.com/q/10432714/2033717 http://stackoverflow.com/q/19189132/2033717

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for null and 0.

```
=IIF(Fields!TotalSales.Value <> 0 , (Fields!Margin.Value) / (Fields!TotalSales.Value) * 100 , 0)
```