# SSRS divide by 0 error even when using iif() isnothing() and =0 or =nothing

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I have a simple % change formula I want to implement into a report... the formula being (a-b)/b.

Issue is sometimes the value for b coming into the data set is blank/null... and furthermore SSRS can't ever seem to accurately realize this through the `iif()` statement I'm using. Instead whenever the report renders, for any line item where data for b in the formula is missing I get the dreaded "ERROR" showing up in that cell. The formula in the cell I'm using is below. What's the issue here? Why can't SSRS see that `sum(b) = nothing` or `isnothing(sum(b))` evaluates to true? It's like it bypasses that part of the formula and goes ahead and does the math, divides by 0 and throws and error?

```
=iif( 
    isnothing(sum(Fields!BR_Quantity.Value))=true or sum(Fields!BR_Quantity.Value)=0 or sum(Fields!BR_Quantity.Value)=nothing,
    nothing,
    (sum(Fields!Full_Case_Quantity.Value)-sum(Fields!BR_Quantity.Value)) / sum(Fields!BR_Quantity.Value)
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS 2008 - Dealing with division by zero scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471817/ssrs-2008-dealing-with-division-by-zero-scenarios)

Answer (score 0):

The IIF function evaluates both the TRUE and FALSE parts of the expression.

Use a separate IIF on both the numerator and denominator:

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(SUM(Fields!BR_Quantity.Value)) OR SUM(Fields!BR_Quantity.Value) = 0, 0, SUM(Fields!Full_Case_Quantity.Value) - SUM(Fields!BR_Quantity.Value)
/
 IIF(ISNOTHING(SUM(Fields!BR_Quantity.Value)) OR SUM(Fields!BR_Quantity.Value) = 0, 1, SUM(Fields!BR_Quantity.Value) )
```

This way when your denominator is 0 or NULL, the resulting expression is `0 / 1` .

Kinda lame but Microsoft won't fix it.

Comment: Ok, I will try this method tomorrow. I totally thought it was lame that the iif() function doesn't work like in t-SQL

Comment: Whats strange about it is that it works without errors if numbers are integers. Also using Cdbl function like =Iif(Fields!b.Value=0,  0 , Cdbl(Fields!a.Value)/Cdbl(Fields!b.Value))  seems to remove the error from the expression

Comment: The best approach in my opinion is by using custom code like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189132/ssrs-expression-divide-by-zero-error . Simple vb code and makes your expressions more readable